# R: Function that finds the range of 95% of all values?

Tags: r

Is there a function or an elegant way in the R language, to get the minimum range, that covers, say 95% of all values in a vector?

Any suggestions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

95% of the data will fall between the 2.5th percentile and 97.5th percentile.  You can compute that value in R as follows:

```
x <- runif(100)
quantile(x,probs=c(.025,.975))
```

To get a sense of what's going on, here's a plot:

```
qts <- quantile(x,probs=c(.05,.95))
hist(x)
abline(v=qts[1],col="red")
abline(v=qts[2],col="red")
```

Note this is the exact/empirical 95% interval; there's no normality assumption.

[image: hist of 95% interval]

Comment: @David Molnar: Do note that this solution makes the implicit assumption that the underlying distribution is symmetric, contrary to your stated desire below that you don't want to introduce any assumptions. If you have a skewed distribution, then you can get a shorter interval by changing the endpoints. Eg if your data is exponential, then `quantile(*, c(0, 0.95))` will produce a shorter interval than `quantile(*, c(0.025, 0.975))`.

Comment: @Hong Ooi:  Precisely.  Thanks for making that explicit.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so hard to write such function:

```
find_cover_region <- function(x, alpha=0.95) {
    n <- length(x)
    x <- sort(x)
    k <- as.integer(round((1-alpha) * n))
    i <- which.min(x[seq.int(n-k, n)] - x[seq_len(k+1L)])
    c(x[i], x[n-k+i-1L])
}
```

Function will find shortest interval. If there are intervals with the same length first (from `-Inf`) will be picked up.

```
find_cover_region(1:100, 0.70)
# [1]  1 70
find_cover_region(rnorm(10000), 0.9973) # three sigma, approx (-3,3)
# [1] -2.859  3.160 # results may differ
```

You could also look on highest density regions (e.g. in [package hdrcde](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdrcde), [function `hdr`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hdrcde/docs/hdr)). It's more statistical way to find shortest intervals with given cover probability (some kernel density estimators are involved).

Answer (score 1):

The emp.hpd function in the TeachingDemos package will find the values in a vector that enclose a given percentage of the data (95%) that also give the shortest range between the values.  If the data is roughly symmetric then this will be close to the results of using quantile, but if the data are skewed then this will give a shorter range.

Comment: Nice, +1. I checked your function and it's almost the same as one in my answer. But I see that you use `min`&`==` combination which can be replaced by `which.min` (`nnn <- which.min(xx)`).

Answer (score 0):

If the values are distributed approximately like the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), you can use the standard deviation. First, calculate the [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) µ and [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the distribution. 95% of the values will be in the interval of (µ - 1.960 * stdev, µ + 1.960 * stdev).

Comment: Thank you Femaref. I should have mentioned, that I would like to introduce no assumption about the data.